# Excel - Iterative calculations convergence issue / infinite loop

Tags: excel, loops, iteration, self-reference

I am developing a vehicle lap time simulation using Microsoft Excel 2016.
The spreadsheet I have built so far is fairly complex and involves few thousands of rows and many circular references between the columns, which are around 50.

The problem I am experiencing is that of calculations not converging: iterations (making use of the built-in algorithm) never stop and values continue to change; in particular, cells containing formulae like "equal to another cell" return values which do not comply with such formulae, being slightly different from those in referenced cells. This happens regardless of the "maximum change" value in the settings.

Results are overall in line with expectations, but these small deviations make the spreadsheet difficult to use because of the never-ending calculations.

One thing I realised is that all columns reference at least another: could this originate the problem, given the lack of an "initial guess"?

Anyway, could this issue be related to any known limitation of the algorithm or is it something that can be solved by adjusting settings or the workbook itself?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you using the solver? If you set the constraints correctly it usually solves if there is a valid solution, but if there isn’t one then the results don’t necessarily mean anything.

Comment: I simply enabled iterative calculations in the settings, did not use the Solver. Is there any difference between the two that could help solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the solver? may be worth it - perhaps use a subset of data

Comment: I have, but it does not seem to work with my spreadsheet: there is no unique "target value" and, anyway, the range of cells to be varied would be immense due to the interconnections between columns.

Comment: These « results » you mention - a maximum, minimum or equal to a value ... if one of those then you should be able to make the solver work - if not then Frontline do a larger solver... But it could also be due to how you have laid out your spreadsheet... there could be another way to lay out the data

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the structure of the spreadsheet at this stage and I do not think it is worth it, given that overall results are satisfactory. I will consider trying another Solver. Thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 2):

I have had situations like this before.  Two tricks I used to get around this are first, to soften the dependency at the references to a fraction of the difference.  Like, cell A1 could be equal to cell B1, but maybe it would be better to make it...

> =A1 + (B1 - A1) / 10

...I know this seems nuts, but you can predict what the computer will do.  Let's say they start at 0 and 100, for instance.  The iterations go:

> B1 = 100
>
> A1 = 0
>
> A1 = 0 + (100) / 10 = 10
>
> A1 = 10 + (100 - 10) / 10 = 19
>
> A1 = 19 + (100 - 19) / 10 = 27.1
>
> ...
>
> A1 ≈ 100 = B1

The other trick I used is to make one cell in the loop a value (keeping a copy of the text of the formula in Notepad for later), then to paste the formula back into that cell.  This is how to get initial conditions for the loop.

Great question!  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, what you pointed out makes sense; in spite of this, it did not help.
A further aspect I did not consider is that my calculations involve referencing cells below that containing the formula, while as far as I know iterations run rightward and downward: could this cause calculations to be "one iteration behind", thus originating the issue?

Comment: I don't know the order of events with iterations... I assume that the entire sheet goes through one iteration entirely before it does another iteration.  The intent with my "softening" practice is to make the next iteration more similar to the past iteration, so that the sequence over time is less unstable.

Comment: I get the idea behind your piece of advice and agree that it could help, but in the end it did not. What I meant in my previous comment is the following: the spreadsheet does go through an iteration entirely before doing another, but some cells may depend on values which are updated after them (because located below) in each iteration, thus making use of "old" values

Comment: The other guy suggested using Solver... if you haven't started this, now's the time.

Comment: If you don't want to use Solver, I would like to talk about my "softening" exercise a little more...

Comment: I checked Solver out, but it does not suit this application or at least I cannot see the way it could be applied. I would certainly be interested in further details on your suggestion

Comment: So generally speaking, I suggest doing this: establish a cell having the softening factor of 10 (example at $Z$2).  Now whenever one cell in your loop refers to another cell (for example cell A1 has formula =B1), change the formula at A1 to =A1 + (B1 - A1) / $Z$2.

Comment: Do this even if A1 is some relation to B1, such as at A1 the formula, =B1 ^ 2 + 1500;   change A1 to this:  =(A1 + (B1 - A1) / $Z$2) ^ 2 + 1500.

Comment: Now once these softening factors have appeared at a couple critical links in your circular loops, hit F9 a couple of times to see what Excel does.

Comment: Keep hitting F9: is it crazy?  Do errors pop out like #VALUE or #DIV/0?

Comment: Do the numbers get huge?  If so, increase $Z$2 to 40 or 100.

Comment: The #NUM! error means that a number has grown to infinity, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try it out and report

Comment: I tried what you suggested: most cells grow to unreasonable values, some show #NUM! errors. The value of the "softening factor" makes virtually no difference. Everything goes crazy since the first iteration.

Comment: Sounds like a math error.  I suggest you debug the math by reducing the iterations to just a couple, and making calculation fully manual.  Then you hit F9 to see which number has the most problems... and audit the equation.

Comment: I was able to make a circular reference in which A = B + 1, while B = A + 1... needless to say this number grew with every iteration.  It was slow enough, however, not to grow into a #NUM! error for me, but it never stabilized and never slowed down

Comment: Some equations and intercell references have this kind of problem intrinsically--- kind of like a monkey wrench in the gears.

Comment: I will thoroughly check all formulae, but I am ready to accept it to stay as it is given that the issue does not impact overall results quality. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It inspire me to do like this for get a convergence on one parameter : H1 
I have a variable depending of it that must go to 0 : J20 
First i set H1 to 0
then set G1=H1
then set H1=G1+J20*(some constant)
with iterative calculation i get my H1 value to obtains J20 near 0